# Error pushing React app to Heroku - "remote rejected main-> main (pre-reseive hook declined)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

I'm gettig this very frustrating erro while trying to push my React app to Heroku. I was able to push it up with no problem in the application's earlier development, but for some reason it now gives me the **same error message all the time:**

[image]

`! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/sapient-origin-alpha.git'`

The only thing I can think of is that there is some issue with the version of react I'm using (I tried react 18 and 17, both gave the same results). But again, I was able to push it up before with no problem so I'm not sure. My other thought was that it's the client-side `package.json` since it's saying the build is failing.

Another thing worth mentioning is that I re-named the Heroku app, but afterwards I removed my local git remote and created a new git remote with the updated Heroku app name. So maybe this had something to do with it? This is basically what I did:

```
*rename heroku app*
$ git remote rm heroku
$ heroku git:remote -a sapient-origin-alpha
```

If anyone is able to help me on this I would very greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I'm just dumb. It literally told me what was wrong in the error message slightly above the text in the image I provided.

The problem was in the client-side `package.json` because of some dependency I was using. Make sure to double check your package.json file for things that could be causing a similar error, and delete your `package-lock.json` then run `npm i` again to refresh the file.